# Are there any error with my boot?

Tags: 10.10, boot

I really feel no error with my Ubuntu 10.10 system to date. but when it boots, I can see some messages display. I read the Boot.log in the /var/log directory and here it is!

Are there any errors when booting or what are the messages display below[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no errors during boot.

Here you are more details:

- `init: ureadahead-other main process (349) terminated with status 4`

  This line means that the process `ureadahead` has finished doing its job and has quit. `ureadahead` is a program that is run to speed up the boot and the exit status 4 is perfectly legitimate (see also `man ureadahead` and `/etc/init/ureadahead-other.conf`).
- `udevd[372]: BUS= will be removed in a future udev version, ...`

  This is a deprecation warning: `udev` will change its programming interface (API) a bit in a future release. This is something that the developers will have to work on, but nothing that prevents the system from working properly.
- `udevd[372]: can not read '/etc/udev/rules.d/z80_user.rules'`

  Here `udevd` is looking for a file that does not exist. It's perfectly OK if you do not have this file: you need it only if you want to customize udev.
- `fsck from ... /dev/loop0: clean, ...`

  `fsck` is a tool that checks your filesystem for errors. "Clean" means that everything is OK.
- The last two lines are just notifications that Apparmor and Sensor Limits are being started.

From your logs, I see that you are running from a CD or some device like that. CD performance are suboptimal, so probably you are seeing the messages because the services are started before the splash screen is shown.

Anyhow, everything is working as expected and you shouldn't worry. I hope to have solved all your doubts :-)

Comment: Thanks, that makes relief. I am not running from a cd or any other removable media. Ubuntu is installed using Wubi and the plymouth theme displays good. I just switched to the command line booting by pressing Delete key and saw those messages. Thanks in advance Your answer helps a lot for me, thanks again!